# Best way to format a query string for tracking

Tags: c#, html, jquery

I am looking for an opinion.

I have some data in an excel which is converted into a Base64 string. This Base64 string is being sent appended to an URL i.e. https://my.site.com/q=Base64

Is this the correct way to do this? The Base64 string contains user information.

I have noted that when we do as above some characters are lost/ replaced hence I have trouble finding the tracking code in the database.

Any guidance will be most helpful.

Most of my code is C# and jQuery

Comment: Is there any sensitive user information on the string? You can always take the base64 and convert it back and maybe that'll give you the info in plain text so its easier to find in database

Comment: It is unclear why you think asking for opinions is on-topic (https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). It is possible that you actually have an on-topic question ("I have trouble finding the tracking code in the database.") but that would need [mre] and somewhat different phrasing.

Comment: Thanks. Noted. Yes the string has sensitive user information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential problem could be that base64 strings can contain the `+`, `=` and `/` characters, which are not URL friendly and could change the meaning of your data. In order to fix that, you have to encode your URL. .NET provides a [HttpUtility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility?view=net-6.0) class that contains methods for encoding and decoding URLs.

A quick example that demonstrates how it could be done:

```
private static string AddArgumentsToUrl(string url, IDictionary<string, string>? queryParameters)
{
    queryParameters ??= new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string argumentsString = string.Join("&", queryParameters.Select(arg => $"{arg.Key}={arg.Value}"));
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(argumentsString) ? $"{url}?{argumentsString}" : url;
}

public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
{
    var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

And you could call it like this:

```
var baseUrl = "https://my.site.com/";
var queryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "q", $"{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Base64Encode("test"))}" }
};
var res = AddArgumentsToUrl(baseUrl, queryParams); // https://my.site.com/?q=dGVzdA%3d%3d
```

Lastly, be sure to decode the URL on the receiving side and then decode the base64 to plain text.